# Usage of 'to' in the below context

Tags: usage

'You(A) watched me(B) crying to sleep'.

From the above statement, what I understood was Person A watched Person B kept crying untill Person B fell asleep.
In the same manner, can anyone tell what 'to' refers to in the following sentences?

1. This Kid is speaking truth to power
2. I will kiss this kitten to cute.

Comment: This is ungrammatical English. Where did you find these sentences?

Comment: @SovereignSun The example sentence in a movie 'The notebook' and the other two in Facebook posts

Comment: "**crying to sleep**" is okay and means "**cry so long that you got asleep**" but the other two sentences are bad.

Comment: You might add why you think the pattern "crying to sleep" applies to "truth to power" and "kitten to cute".

Answer (score 1):

The first example is OK, a more complete phrasing might be:

> You watched me *while I cried myself* to sleep.

The two from Facebook are just wrong. Without any context, my guesses would be:

> This Kid is speaking a powerful truth.
>   I will kiss this (too) cute kitten.